# Issues with Hospital Charges Function Problems in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, function

I'm making a program in VB where I have to make three different functions to determine costs from numbers input in my hospital charges form. One to calculate the misc charges(CalcMiscCharges), one to calculate to cost of the hospital stay(CalcChargesOfStay), and one to determine the total charges(CalctotalCharges). With this current code any numbers I put in are being answered with 0 dollars. Can anyone see where my issue lies?

```
Const DayRate As Decimal = 350
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'declare variables
    Dim PhysicalRehab As Decimal
    Dim SurgeryCharges As Decimal
    Dim LabCharges As Decimal
    Dim MedCharges As Decimal
    Dim StayCharges As Decimal
    Try
        'Copy the scores into the variables
        StayCharges = CDec(TextBoxLength.Text) * DayRate
        MedCharges = CDec(TextBoxMed.Text)
        SurgeryCharges = CDec(TextBoxSurg.Text)
        LabCharges = CDec(TextBoxLab.Text)
        PhysicalRehab = CDec(TextBoxPhy.Text)
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter numeric values", "Error")
        Return
    End Try
    'Find out if box enteries are negative or not
    If Convert.ToDecimal(LabCharges) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
        Return
        TextBoxLab.SelectAll()
    ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(MedCharges) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
        Return
        TextBoxMed.SelectAll()
    ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(SurgeryCharges) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
        Return
        TextBoxSurg.SelectAll()
    ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(PhysicalRehab) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
        Return
        TextBoxPhy.SelectAll()
    ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(StayCharges) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
        Return
        TextBoxLength.SelectAll()
    End If
    'Sends results to the label
    LabelTotal.Text = CalctotalCharges.ToString("c")
End Sub
Function CalcMiscCharges() As Decimal
    Return CDec(TextBoxMed.Text) + CDec(TextBoxLab.Text) + CDec(TextBoxPhy.Text) + CDec(TextBoxSurg.Text)
End Function
Function CalcChargesOfStay() As Decimal
    Return CalcChargesOfStay = CDec(TextBoxLength.Text) * DayRate
End Function

Function CalctotalCharges() As Decimal
    Return CDec(CalctotalCharges = CDec(CalcChargesOfStay() + CalcMiscCharges()))
End Function

Private Sub ButtonExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClear.Click
    TextBoxLab.Clear()
    TextBoxLength.Clear()
    TextBoxMed.Clear()
    TextBoxPhy.Clear()
    TextBoxSurg.Clear()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're mixing two different syntaxes in these functions:

```
Function CalcChargesOfStay() As Decimal
    Return CalcChargesOfStay = CDec(TextBoxLength.Text) * DayRate
End Function

Function CalctotalCharges() As Decimal
    Return CDec(CalctotalCharges = CDec(CalcChargesOfStay() + CalcMiscCharges()))
End Function
```

Either **only** use the `Return` keyword, or **only** set the `function name` to the result.

So it could look like this:

```
Function CalcChargesOfStay() As Decimal
    Return CDec(TextBoxLength.Text) * DayRate
End Function

Function CalctotalCharges() As Decimal
    Return CalcChargesOfStay() + CalcMiscCharges()
End Function
```

Or like this:

```
Function CalcChargesOfStay() As Decimal
    CalcChargesOfStay = (CDec(TextBoxLength.Text) * DayRate)
End Function

Function CalctotalCharges() As Decimal
    CalctotalCharges = (CalcChargesOfStay() + CalcMiscCharges())
End Function
```

But you can't use both syntaxes.